# Error Appstore connect : Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File (NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription)

Tags: ios, app-store, info.plist

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   . Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File - Your app's code references
>   one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist
>   file should contain a NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a
>   user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
>   app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
>   App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose
>   string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
>   APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
>   APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
>   developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
>   their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Actually, I am not trying to use to access bluetooth. But somehow App Store reject my app like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you added `CoreBluetooth.framework` in **linked libraries and frameworks** section in **Build phases** , remove it.

Also, check if any third party libraries that you are using in the project uses bluetooth. Check if any files import `CoreBluetooth.framework`

Comment: didn't added CoreBluetooth.framework. Anyway thank you... still facing that issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you using advertising frameworks ? 
Ad frameworks sometime use bluetooth information.